# How to reverse search in regex?

Tags: php, regex

I have 3 different strings:

1. http://site.com/id-name_of_news.html
2. http://site.com/category/subcategory/id-name_of_news.html
3. http://site.com/2008/04/02/name_of_news.html

From each of this i need to get `name_of_news` string which can contain almost all symbols. I think it would be wise to go from the `.html` until first `/123-` (slash with id) or `/02/` (date) but cant figure out how to do it in more proper way... May be somebody could help me?

Comment: Could you show some of your attempts?

Comment: Таке part of а string after the last `/`

Comment: @Jerry tried something like this `\.html?(.*)/`

Comment: This regex means 'capture everything after `.html` (with `l` optional), which won't really capture anythin useful from your samples. Can the `name_of_news` contain slashes?

Comment: @Jerry i think no, as i looked through db now there only can be `a-zA-Z-.`

Comment: strrpos  May help -> http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to go in reverse. You can build the regex to get that part in a capture group.

You can use this regex:

```
~.*?/(?:\d+-)?([^/]*)\.html~
```

... and get the group 1.

```
~
  ^
  .*      # match everything
  /       # Till the last `/`
  (?:     # Non-capturing group
     \d+-   # One or more digits followed by a hyphen
  )?      # Optional
  (       # Capture group 1
     [^/.]*  # Match anything except `/` or `.`
  )       
  \.     # Match a dot
  html    # html (at the end)
  $
~
```

Comment: @Jerry Here comes the Java Developer. ;)

Comment: Still found it strange that you didn't double escape everything else =P

Comment: thanks man, did some modifications for php and it worked almost fine... Is it possible not to capture the `id-` if it exists? Id contains number (can be 1, 10, 100, 1000....) and `-`.

Comment: @user1692333 The regex isn't capturing the id's. It's using a non-capturing group.

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = 'http://site.com/id-name_of_news.html';
var_dump(end(explode('/', $url)));
```

**OR**

```
$url = 'http://site.com/id-name_of_news.html';
var_dump(substr($url, strrpos($url, '/')+1));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this pattern:

```
~http://[^/\s]+/(?:(?:[^/\s]+/){2,3})?(?:id-)?\K[^\s]+(?=\.html)~
```

which give you the result with the whole pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need regex for this. You can use following alternate approach:

1. Find position of `.html` from end using `$pos = strrpos($url, '.html');`
2. Find nearest `/` from backwards of `pos` again using `$slashpos = strrpos($url, '/', $pos * -1);`
3. Take substring of `$url` starting from `$slashpos` to `$pos`